# Get tag, custom taxonomy and attachment data from get_pages function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I currently have some code which retrieves all pages submitted by the currently logged in author using the get_pages function. I am then passing the result to Javascript via Ajax. Everything works as expected, and I'm retrieving the pages that I should be.

My issue is, the object does not have any data for the tags, other custom taxonomies and attachments on this page.

Is there a way to attach this data to the returned object?

functions.php:

```
function get_ajax_pages()
{
    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
        'authors' => $author,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending'),
        'hierarchical' => 0
    );

    // The Query
    $ajaxpages = get_pages($args);

    echo json_encode($ajaxpages);

    exit;
}

// Fire AJAX action for both logged in and non-logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_pages', 'get_ajax_pages');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_pages', 'get_ajax_pages');
```

Javascript:

```
var adminAjaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";

// the list of pages by the current author
    var pageList = [];

    // get an array of the current author's pages
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: adminAjaxUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { action: 'get_ajax_pages' },
        success: function (response) {
            pageList = response;
        }
    });
```

At this point, each entry will return something like:

```
ID: 100
comment_count: "0"
comment_status: "open"
filter: "raw"
guid: "https://example.com/?page_id=100"
menu_order: 0
ping_status: "closed"
pinged: ""
post_author: "1"
post_content: "This is the post content"
post_content_filtered: ""
post_date: "2021-06-18 10:00:00"
post_date_gmt: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
post_excerpt: "This is the excerpt"
post_mime_type: ""
post_modified: "2021-06-18 10:00:00"
post_modified_gmt: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
post_name: ""
post_parent: 19
post_password: ""
post_status: "pending"
post_title: "Example page"
post_type: "page"
to_ping: ""
```

I would like it to also include data along the lines of:

```
tags: "example, test"
myCustomTaxonomy: "extra information, more data"
attachments: "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/myImage.png"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it's useful, this is the solution I came up with. It certainly may not be efficient but it appears to suit my purposes at least.

What I ended up doing was populating a select list with each of the pages found in the first AJAX call. Selecting a page in this list then calls the second function which gets the various extra metadata for that page.

functions.php:

```
function get_ajax_pages()
{
    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
        'authors' => $author,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending'),
        'hierarchical' => 0
    );

    // The Query
    $ajaxPages = get_pages($args);

    echo json_encode($ajaxPages);

    exit;
}

// Fire AJAX action for both logged in and non-logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_pages', 'get_ajax_pages');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_pages', 'get_ajax_pages');

function get_ajax_meta()
{
    $editId = $_POST['editId'];

    $meta = [];

    $editTags = get_the_tags($editId);
    $editCustomTaxonomy1 = get_the_terms($editId, 'CustomTaxonomy1');
    $editCustomTaxonomy2 = get_the_terms($editId, 'CustomTaxonomy2');
    $media = get_attached_media('', $editId);

    array_push($meta, (object)[
        'tags' => $editTags,
        'customTaxonomy1' => $customTaxonomy1,
        'customTaxonomy1' => $customTaxonomy2,
        'media' => $media
    ]);

    echo json_encode($meta);

    exit;
}

// Fire AJAX action for both logged in and non-logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_meta', 'get_ajax_meta');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_meta', 'get_ajax_meta');
```

Javascript:

```
var adminAjaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";

// the list of pages by the current author
var pageList = [];

// get an array of the current author's pages
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: adminAjaxUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    data: { action: 'get_ajax_pages' },
    success: function (response) {
        pageList = response;

        // populate the dropdown with the pages
        if (pageList.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < pageList.length; i++) {
                $("select[name=edit-page]").append("<option value='" + pageList[i].ID + "'>" + pageList[i].post_title + "</option>");
            }
        }
    }
});

$("body").on("change", "select[name=edit-page]", function () {
    editId = $(this).val();

    // get the meta information of the selected page (tags, custom taxonomies, attached files)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: adminAjaxUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "editId": editId, action: "get_ajax_meta" },
        success: function (response) {
            pageMeta = response;

            // get the tags
            console.log(pageMeta[0].tags[i].name)

            // get custom taxonomy 1 data
            console.log(pageMeta[0].customTaxonomy1[i].name)

            // get custom taxonomy 2 data
            console.log(pageMeta[0].customTaxonomy2[i].name)

            // get attached file data
            if (Object.keys(pageMeta[0].media).length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(pageMeta[0].media).length; i++) {
                    console.log(pageMeta[0].media[Object.keys(pageMeta[i].media)[0]]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```